# How to align bootstrap dropdown menus underneath selected nav item

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get the "Big Dropdown" menu to display right underneath the nav item. I have set a max-width to the menu but I cannot seem to get it to align properly. I would prefer an all responsive solution & the "cleanest" way to achieve this without having to adjust all the little things.

The green box is where I would like the dropdowns to be "naturally" positioned at, the dropdown being its current WRONG position, so the ideal solution would be if I were to add more nav items and each dropdown would be placed respectively under their nav items.

[image: Dropdown in the wrong position, green outline is ideal position]

**HTML**

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown position-static">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" 
    id="navbarDropdown" role="button">Big Dropdown</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu midmenu ">
        <div class="row">
            <li class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                    <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                    <hr>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-6">
                <ul>
                    <h6 class="list-header">List Header</h6>
                    <hr>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
           </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
nav.main .megamenu {
    padding: 20px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 1500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

nav.main .midmenu {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    float: left;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    max-width: 650px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

**Codepen** - Please See "Big Dropdown"
https://codepen.io/GH5ST/pen/GGgWPK

Comment: did my answer not work for you ? You downvoted it ?

Comment: I did not downvote your answer I don't know why it disappeared..

Comment: Can you see it now ?Let me know if it doesnt work for you. I will delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged that you're using Bootstrap 4, there is actually a built-in class to right align dropdowns called `dropdown-menu-right`. The documentation can be found in the [Menu alignment section](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment) of the Bootstrap 4 documentation.

Note that since you are using a nav-menu, this will align the dropdown to the right of the page and not the right of the dropdown button.

The updated is the updated Codepen example can be found [here](https://codepen.io/ChaseIngebritson/pen/VdYQRa).

Edit: I [forked the Codepen example again](https://codepen.io/ChaseIngebritson/pen/jKEzPe) and added a bit of Javascript and CSS in to right align the dropdown menu with the dropdown button instead of the right side of the screen.

Comment: No problem! Also, you may need to adjust the media query that I added to "disable" the listener, right now it just forces the dropdown menu to the right using `right: auto !important;`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style

```
.dropdown-menu.megamenu.midmenu.show {
    right: 0;
  }
  .dropdown-menu.show {
    right: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!! This solution also works well but the above solution is much more fit for my purpose.

Comment: I agree with you . Thats why I deleted my answer earlier. Just wanted to be sure that it works or not. Thanks